# how to reference a value in a C# array

Tags: c#

i have the following array :

```
int[] myArray = {21,21,364,658,87};
```

and a reference to the second element like so:

```
int rr = myArray[1];
```

i want something like :
 `rr = 500`

```
Console.writeLine(myArray[1]);// ---> should print 500 !
```

i hope you guys got my idea , i can do this easily in python like the example above.
so 
how to do this in C#

Comment: how come you expect `500` without having any such value in `myArray` ?

Comment: where does the `500` comes from? Your example has no `500`, is it a sum of somekind?

Comment: Why won't you just use `myArray[1] = 500;` ?

Comment: on what basis, you got rr = 500?

Comment: the idea is : in python i just use rr = 500 to update the array. so rr is a reference ( read the title ) . but in C# i can't get a reference this way .. how do i get it .. that's my question

Comment: It seems that @MoayyadYaghi wants to do something like pointer to element inside array, so `rr` is alias for `myArray[1]`

Comment: @des yes that's exactly what im trying to say

Comment: @MoayyadYaghi then you may consider reading: [How to: Access an Array Element with a Pointer (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/199338w1(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @des thanks man ! you should post it as an answer to get the reputation. and sorry for my bad question. i never used C# ( never will) . but i was asked to write a couple of lines to run some game at work. :D

Comment: @MoayyadYaghi You need to grasp the concept of value types in C#. In contracts to Ruby or other dynamic languages, trivial types are value types - simple types which are always passed by transfering the copy of their values. The cleanest way to accomplish what you are up to was IMHO proposed by armen.shimon which I'd recommend to use.

Comment: What's your reason to do this? *Why* are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

my solution would probably be create property with `arr[1]` as its backing property

something like:

```
  public int rr
  {
    set{ arr[1] = value;}
    get{ return arr[1];}
  }
```

and than `rr=500;` will be the same as `arr[1]=500;`

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like this:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static Action<int> CreateSetter(this int[] array, int index)
    {
        return (value) => array[index] = value;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ArrayTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        int[] myArray = {21,21,364,658,87};
        Action<int> rr = myArray.CreateSetter(1);
        rr(500);
        Assert.AreEqual(500, myArray[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
int[] myArray = {21,21,364,658,87};
int rr = myArray[1];
rr = 500;
```

You will only overwrite the value in rr, there is no way for you to get the actual memory address of an arrays inner elements, and thereby updating it.

My answer must therefore be:

```
myArray[1] = 500;
```

I'm trying to understand what you're trying to do, if you want to encapsulate your change in a function you could pass the reference on this way, but it's all about what you want to do with it:

```
    public void Proc()
    {
        var ints = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        FunctionChangingByReference(ref ints[1]);
    }

    public void FunctionChangingByReference(ref int x)
    {
        x = 500;
    }
```

In C# there are no pointers, only references.

(I'm lying a bit, you could use pointers if you create a unsafe context, but we don't do that in C#, and neither should you. When we code C++ we do, but that's C++, and we do it at a cost, we make the code a bit more fragile and error prone. When I code C# I try to optimize the code on a higher level than memory address shuffling. If you really need to optimize on that level you should write the code in C++ and import that code as a dll, then you have a good separation of concern, and don't forget to test drive the development!)

Comment: Actually, in C# almost everything is a pointer, not a reference. Everything that's `class`. `int` is a struct, hence the problem.

Comment: int is an immutable value type (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx). Int32 is a struct though, but this is not to be confused with the int value type. C# uses references out of the box, you can only use pointers in usafe contexts (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx).

Comment: What I meant is because of `Application foo = null;` those behave more like pointers than references (in C++ sense). The only true, unmutable references are ref and out function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Simply `myArray[1] = 500`! You could use a property as Nahum Litvin has suggested if you specifically want a reference to a specific integer within the array.

Answer (score 1):

@des answer has awaken my interest. So I tried his solution and it works as expected:

```
int[] numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
fixed (int* number = &numbers[0])
{
  *number = 10;
}
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", numbers)); // Outputs "10, 2, 3"
```

You have to compile it with the `/unsafe` option.

I hope you see that this may bring some problems.
Therefore **I don't recommend this solution**.

Comment: I don't know much about it but when I tried it without the fixed-stmt the compiler gave me this error: `You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a basically pointer to a variable.
It's hard to explain the difference between "value type" (like `int` or `struct`), a reference and a pointer. I can only recommend learning C.

Here's solution that works, although it may need a lot of changes to your code.

```
//a class that will hold an int inside
public class myIntWrapper
{
    //this is the value wrapper holds
    public int theValue;
    //constructor taking the value
    public myIntWrapper(int argument)
    {
        theValue = argument;
    }

    //operator to convert an int into brand-new myIntWrapper class
    public static implicit operator myIntWrapper(int argument)
    {
        return new myIntWrapper(argument);
    }

    //operator to convert a myIntWrapper class into an int
    public static implicit operator int(myIntWrapper wrapper)
    {
        return wrapper.theValue;
    }
}
```

now you can write:

```
//create an array -
//setting values to every item in array works 
//thanks to operator myIntWrapper(int argument)
myIntWrapper[] myArray = new myIntWrapper[5]{1,2,3,4,5};

//now take a "reference"
myIntWrapper rr = myArray[1];

//change the value
rr.theValue = 500;
//from now on myArray[1].theValue is 500;

//thanks to operator int(myIntWrapper wrapper)
//you can write:
int ss = rr;//it works!
```

please remember to never do:
`rr = 600;`
because this will actually create brand new myIntWrapper, that's not "connected" anywhere.
So remember:

```
rr.theValue = 500;//this changes the value somewhere
rr = myArray[3];//this changes where rr is "pointing" to
```

Yes, it's quite complicated but I doubt it can be done any simpler without unsafe code. I'm sorry for not explaining it more. I'll answer to all questions in comments.